# Blurry Fonts in XFCE

Tags: 11.10, fonts, xfce, nvidia

Since my system was laggy in Gnome 3 i switched to XFCE, but now all the titlebar and menu fonts are blurry but the fonts in chromium seem normal. The Nvidia config tell that my refresh rate is 75Hz this is the maximum supported by my CRT display.However the XFCE Config says its 50Hz

> **SPECS:**
>
> Ubuntu 11.10
>
> Nvidia Zotac 6200
>
> Intel Pentium 4 2.93Ghz
>
> 2GB DDR1 Memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Settings/Appearance and play with the Hinting at the Fonts tab; if you really use a CRT display, you should also turn sub-pixel hinting off.