# Colored text on terminal is fuzzy

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, fonts

I recently re-installed xubuntu 14.04.  I used the font "Proggy Clean (Slashed Zero)" at as size of 12.  Normal text seems to be fine, but when there is colored text, it gets a bit fuzzy (i.e. there is an extra set of vertical pixels on each glyph).

My previous installation didn't have this issue.  Any help on solving this problem would be appreciated.  I really like this font and would hate to have to switch to something else because of a stupid issue like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here:  [Blurry Fonts in XFCE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66126/blurry-fonts-in-xfce)

Needed to set "Sub-pixel order," to "None," in "Settings/Apperance/Fonts/Rendering."